# Is there a way to color text in Python?

Tags: python

I am new to Python and recently I've made a Mastermind game, and right now I use *X* and *O* for checking if you guessed right, but if it possible that I for example use colors for this? I can't find an answer online, I've only found something like

```
x = Color('#FF0000')
```

but that doesn't work, it gives me a syntax error

Comment: Are you using the python console or `Tkinter` or `pygame` or what?

Comment: Oh I didn't know that was important, I just use notepad++ for writing the code, and then I save it as .py and open it with software I downloaded from python.org

Comment: Curses, if only there were a way to make colored terminal graphics like the old nethack game.

Comment: You can't I believe. Correct me if I'm wrong. You should look into `Tkinter` or `pygame`. High initial startup devotion but pays off in the long run.

Comment: Here, this should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html

Comment: Here's a [code example on how to print red circle in a terminal in random places](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22121542/4279)

Comment: @Paul: For colored output in a terminal, `blessings` (+ `colorama` for Windows) modules are much simpler and cleaner than curses. See [example I've linked above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22121542/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?
[Print in terminal with colors using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python)
Basically, you do it by printing [ANSI escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences.php).
For example:

> print '\x1b[31mThis is sentence is red\x1b[m'