# Print to a previously printed line

Tags: python, time, printing, console, clock

So Im attempting to creat a simple clock using a series of printed "text blocks" if you will. Im testing it out now with a time of 9:50. My code is below:

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
hour=now.hour
minute=now.minute
#This next part clears the console window
import os
clear = lambda: os.system('cls')
clear()
print()
print()
#This part converts military time to standard time and makes sure is printed correctly
M=""
if hour>=12:
    M="PM"
if hour<12:
    M="AM"
if hour>12:
    hour=hour-12
if minute<10:
    minute="0"+minute
#print (("%s:%s"+ " " + M) % (hour, minute))
def ninehour():
    #prints a 9 in the hour slot, includes colon
    print("*********")
    print("**     **")
    print("**     **    **")
    print("**     **    **")
    print("*********")
    print("       **    **")
    print("       **    **")
    print("       **")
    print("*********")
def fourminutetens(minute):
    print("                  **     **")
    print("                  **     **")
    print("                  **     **")
    print("                  *********")
    print("                         **")
    print("                         **")
    print("                         **")
def fiveminutetens(minute):
    #Prints a 5 in the tens slot (50 minutes)
    print("                  *********")
    print("                  **       ")
    print("                  **       ")
    print("                  *********")
    print("                         **")
    print("                         **")
    print("                  *********")
def printhour(hour):
    if hour==9:
        ninehour()
def printminuteten(minute):
    if minute>39 and minute<50:
        fourminutetens(minute)
    if minute>49 and minute<60:
        fiveminutetens(minute)
 printhour(hour)
 printminuteten(minute)
```

However; When this prints to console it will first print the "9:" and then the 5 will be printed below it as opposed to beside it like a clock disply (an obvious error). is there anyway to fix this without creating a function for every possible hour minute combination?

Answer (score 0):

To overwrite a single line, you could use `\r` instead of a newline:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import time
from itertools import cycle

for i, c in zip(range(101), cycle("\-/|")):
    sys.stderr.write("\r{} {:.0%}".format(c, i/1e2))
    time.sleep(.3)
```

To overwrite multiple lines, you need an ability to put cursor at arbitrary position in a terminal. You could [use `blessings` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blessings/). Here's [code example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22121542/4279).