# python - How to use raw_input in center of terminal

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I need get input from user in center of terminal, I know how to print string at center with function center(width[,filler]) but i couldn't find anything how to centrize input (or anywhere else) ?

Comment: How are you centering  your output? With ncurses or something?

Comment: just use str.center(Twidth) that Termial width can find by function in follow link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/566746/how-to-get-console-window-width-in-python

Comment: You could try [`blessings`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/blessings/) + `colorama`. Here's [code example that shows a red dot randomly walking in the terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22121542/4279). Or try `raw_input(message.rjust(terminal_width // 2))`.