# Plotting in Python?

Tags: python, graph

I wrote a program in Python that calculates a random walk for an array given certain parameters.

I presume the "random" function is working, since I get the output " (I am using iPython). However, I cannot plot the function on a graph, because the float() argument must be a string or number, not a function. Nevertheless, given the recursive nature of the variables in question, it needs to be defined as a function for the program to run.

How can I graph this?

Comment: loosely related: [random walk in the terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22121542/4279).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
randomnumbers = np.random.normal((mu*(price/10)), (v*(price/10)), days) #This variable generates a series of random numbers based on the normal distribution and in accordance with the return and volatility specified.
randomwalk    = [simAssetPrice[i-1] + randomnumbers[i] + k for i in range(1,days)]

plt.plot(randomwalk)
plt.ylabel('Price')
plt.show()
```

I had to use one more random number then you specified.

In place of your `randomwalk()` function, I've used a list comprehension.

Using the same names for variables as for functions is bound to mess things up. Also, since you wrote:

```
randomwalk
plt.plot(randomwalk)
```

You were referring to a "pointer" to the function. You need to write `randomwalk(simAssetPrice, randomnumbers)` in order to **call** the function.

You may want to review how functions work in Python.

Comment: Thanks Richard. It worked in graphing the plot. However, the reason I defined it as a function was because it wasn't generating a random walk. In other words, the array was scattered around the straight-line return in a zig-zag fashion, because the calculation is not iterating from the previous variable (for price), and that still seems to be an issue. Could you assist in any way?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. What are the axes you are expecting on your graph?

Comment: Essentially, I am looking to generate a random walk for the stock price (with the x axis being number of days and y being the price). However, instead of a random walk, what is happening is that the stock price is simply oscillating up and down in a zig-zag fashion (http://imgur.com/nGaAcq2). This is because the array generated is not iteratively calculating the next day's price because we are simply adding randomness to the entire array.

Comment: Never mind, I solved it by redefining the price variable to include the random element right off the bat, thus saving the need for a recursive function.